# Typescript String Literal Type in generic function

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a function with one generic parameter, but with two function parameters.
When I use "String Literal Type" the two function parameter can be have differt values:

```
function func2<T extends 'A' | 'B'>(x: T, y: T): void { }

func2('A', 'A'); // OK
func2('A', 'B'); // OK, why?
func2('A', 'C'); // ERR
```

But I need that `x` and `y` are the same, like the example with Classes:

```
class A {  public a;}
class B {  public b;}
class C {  public c;}

function func1<T extends A | B>(x: T, y: T): void { }

func1(new A(), new A()); // OK
func1(new A(), new B()); // ERR
func1(new A(), new C()); // ERR
```

Is there any way that `x` and `y` have the same value with "String Literal Type"?

Comment: The parameters both match the constraint, and the order is irrelevant so the appropriate inference is taking place, however you can write `func2<T extends 'A' | 'B', U extends T>(x: T, y: U)`. That makes the second constraint depend on the first

Comment: Thanks Aluan Haddad that solves my problem. I am new to Stackoverflow, how can I mark your answer as the solution?

Comment: Oh, this isn't an answer, it's a comment. I'll add an answer later

Answer (score 1):

Aluan Haddad's comment solves the problem:

> The parameters both match the constraint, and the order is irrelevant so the appropriate inference is taking place, however you can write func2(x: T, y: U). That makes the second constraint depend on the first

Now both parameters can only have the same value:

```
function func2<T extends 'A' | 'B', U extends T>(x: T, y: U): void { }

func2('A', 'A'); // OK
func2('A', 'B'); // ERR
func2('A', 'C'); // ERR
```